# Adding a string based on a condition with a loop in R

Tags: r, string, lapply

For a paper I need results with the form mean ± SD. There are 4 situations:

- no grouping factor (df has data from only one molecule, for example), no units: mean ± sd
- grouping factor, no units
- no grouping factor, with units: mean ± sd ml
- grouping factor, with units

I've made a function that solves the first three situations, but I can't do the last. Below is an example:

```
df <- data.frame(treatment = c(rep(c("Stimulation", "Control"), 8)),
                 group = c(rep(c("A", "B"), 4),
                           rep(c("B", "A"), 4)),
                 value = rnorm(16, mean = 150, sd = 20))

df$units <- ifelse(df$group == "A", "ml", "min")

strg <- function(df, vec, u){
  l <- lapply(levels(vec), function(x){

  list(
    Stimulation = paste(
      myround(mean(df$value[vec==x & df$treatment=="Stimulation"]), 2), "±",
      myround(sd(df$value[vec==x & df$treatment=="Stimulation"]), 2)
    ),
    Control = paste(
      myround(mean(df$value[vec==x & df$treatment=="Control"]), 2), "±",
      myround(sd(df$value[vec==x & df$treatment=="Control"]), 2)
    ))
})
  set_names(l, levels(vec))
}

a <- strg(df, vec = df$group, u = df$units)

add_unit <- function(list, vec, u){
  z <- lapply(list, function(x){
    list(
      Stimulation = paste(x$Stimulation, u[vec==x]),
      Control = paste(x$Control, u[vec==x]))
  })
}

b <- add_unit(a, vec = df$group, u = df$units)
```

The problem seems to be the u[vec==x] bit. The final output needs to have mean ± sd and matched units. How can I add the unit while matching the grouping factor?

EDIT:
The final result should look like this, when grouping exists and we want to add units

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$Stimulation
[1] "154.37 ± 15.9 ml"

[[1]]$Control
[1] "153.32 ± 15.79 ml"


[[2]]
[[2]]$Stimulation
[1] "152.24 ± 17.78 min"

[[2]]$Control
[1] "138.48 ± 31.96 min"
```

if no units are needed it should rather look like this:

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$Stimulation
[1] "154.37 ± 15.9"

[[1]]$Control
[1] "153.32 ± 15.79"


[[2]]
[[2]]$Stimulation
[1] "152.24 ± 17.78"

[[2]]$Control
[1] "138.48 ± 31.96"
```

(basically what I tried to do is was to create the above strings in "a" and then add the unit to the end, if needed, resulting in "b")

Comment: Welcome to SO: Edit your question and add an *ideal* `b` we can use a validation data.

Comment: And `a`. Your code is blowing up in `paste`.

Comment: @ShawnMehan I added two examples. Is that what you were asking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole thing rewritten in [tidyverse](http://tidyverse.org/), where (in my opinion;) the intent of the code is much more legible and manageable:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(group, treatment) %>%
  summarise(
    mean = mean(value),
    sd = sd(value)) %>%
  mutate(
    msd = paste(round(mean, 2), "±", round(sd, 2)),
    unit = group %>% recode(A = "ml", B = "min", .default = ""),
    result = if_else(unit == "",
                     msd,
                     paste(msd, unit)))
```

The calculation / aggregation is separated from the formatting, units are depending on the `group` variable. It's not completely clear what you want to achieve (too many intertwined cases in the question), but you get the results with/witout units in `msd` and `result` columns respectively.

Comment: You are right, this is much easier to manage! There is actually no need for the recode step. This does what I want and I can save it as a function:
`df %>%
    group_by(group, treatment, units) %>%
    summarise(
      mean = mean(value),
      sd = sd(value)) %>%
    mutate(
      msd = paste(round(mean, 2), "±", round(sd, 2)),
      result = paste(msd, units))`

Comment: just to make this more dynamic, is there a clean way to _not_ include "group" in the group_by line if none is provided? I could add an if statement and repeat the code again without it, or even write a separate function, but for such a small thing?

Comment: It's easier to assign all your data to a single group before the call, parametrization of dplyr calls is a bit ugly.